# after new ram install (asus k555ub-XO99D laptop)

Tags: ram

I add new 4gb ram in my laptop,but ubuntu dont recognize it.
laptop has a 4gb onboard ram, and i have add Kingston 4gb new ram.

```
  goksel@goksel:~$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Bellek:        3369         789        1737          87         842        2268
Takas:         2047           0        2047
```

but

```
goksel@goksel:~$ sudo lshw -short -C memory 
[sudo] password for goksel: 
H/W path       Aygıt      Sınıf        Açıklama
====================================================
/0/0                       memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/d                       memory         64KiB L1 önbellek
/0/e                       memory         64KiB L1 önbellek
/0/f                       memory         512KiB L2 önbellek
/0/10                      memory         3MiB L3 önbellek
/0/12                      memory         4GiB Sistem Belleği ----> ?
/0/12/0                    memory         4GiB SODIMM DDR3 Eşzamanlı 1600 MHz -----> ?
/0/12/1                    memory         Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-B
/0/100/1f.2                memory         Memory controller
```

and i have this;

```
goksel@goksel:~$ sudo dmidecode –type memory
# dmidecode 3.1
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.0.0 present.
Table at 0x000ED140.

Handle 0x0012, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 16 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x0013, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0012
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Manufacturer: SK Hynix
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: HMT451S6CFR6A-PB  
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
    Configured Voltage: 1.35 V

Handle 0x0014, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0012
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: Unknown
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
    Configured Voltage: Unknown

Handle 0x0015, DMI type 19, 31 bytes
Memory Array Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x000FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 4 GB
    Physical Array Handle: 0x0012
    Partition Width: 1

Handle 0x0016, DMI type 221, 12 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        DD 0C 16 00 01 01 00 01 04 00 00 00
    Strings:
        Reference Code - ACPI

Handle 0x0017, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x000FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 4 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x0013
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x0015
    Partition Row Position: Unknown
    Interleave Position: 1
    Interleaved Data Depth: 1
```

Whast is a problem?

Comment: Hello, your choice of words makes it unclear what is the case and what is expected? did you **add** 4Gigabytes of RAM to an **already** 4Gigabytes RAM PC and were expecting a **total of 8GB** available RAM after install? is that it?

Comment: yes, exactly what you say.

Comment: a laptop **is** a Personal Computer. did you do the ram instalation yourself?

Comment: Yes,i did.  New, ram is working on other laptop.

Comment: Does your motherboard support that much RAM, many older boards had limits on size, or size per slot and speeds. Have you updated UEFI from vendor?

Comment: Motherboard supports 8gb ram. And i know, This Ram is fully compatible with it.

Comment: https://www.asus.com/Laptops/X55U/specifications/ no it doesn't. https://forums.tomsguide.com/threads/maximum-supported-ram-for-asus-x55u.189413/

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.. 
I typed the computer model wrong . True model is: asus k555ub - xo99d, and It supports 8Gb ram.

Comment: give us a link to support that claim.

Comment: https://www.dunyagrup.com/asus-k555ub-xo099d-4gb-ddr3-1600mhz-ram-bellek-sodimm.html

Comment: 4GB already available in motherboard, if motherboard will not support more, why have empty slots?

Comment: And now , I've solved the problem, thanks for your answers.After cleaning the ram slot with a toothbrush, it fixed :))

Comment: Please don't put "SOLVED" in the title. Write your solution in the window below marked "Your Answer". Then put the green check mark next to your answer to mark it as correct. This will help others.

Comment: Please add an answer to your question and describe how you resolve your problem. SODIMM not sitting properly in the slot or bad contacts is quite common. If you add an answer and accept it, it will help others with similar problem. Cheers.